# Red Hat 8 - Policy-based Routing

Tags: static-routes

I have a issue with routing inside the RH8 server.

So the concept is:

1x Red Hat server with 2 interfaces (different VLANs; 150 & 160)

interfaces teamed like:

1. IP 192.168.50.150 - interface: team0.150
2. IP 192.168.60.200 - interface: team1.160

1x Windows 2012 R2 server with 1 interface (different VLAN; 180)

1. IP 182.10.50.180

- Windows can ping/ssh/telnet to 192.168.50.150 (vice- versa) and it is routed via network equipment but there is a need to access other IP 192.168.60.200 on the same server from Windows server but it is isolated network and it cannot be done via physical layer..

so I create IP routes as followed:

RED HAT server:
182.10.50.180 via 192.168.50.1 dev team0.150 metric 405

Windows server:
192.168.60.200 255.255.255.0 192.168.50.150

On the Red Hat server:

- ip forward is enabled

cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
1

- rp filter is set to loose on all interfaces

sysctl -w "net.ipv4.conf.all.rp_filter=2"
net.ipv4.conf.all.rp_filter=2

I cannot just forward all packets from interface team0.150 to team1.160 because other traffic is also coming to both interfaces.

Ping is not working between interfaces team0.150 and team1.160 when I specify interface, otherwise it works somehow.

Firewalls are down localy on the servers and all ports are allowed on physical firewall.
What else should I try to make it work?

Thanks!

Comment: If you can, please include configuration file as well for further clarity.

Comment: @JohnGreene - solution could only work via VPN, because of poor performance it is declined